# Finding an eigenvalue of a special cubic graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

My question is about a cubic graph $G$ that is the edge-disjoint union of subgraphs isomorphic to the graph $H$ that is as below:

[image]

I want to prove that $0$ is an eigenvalue of the adjacency matrix of $G$.

I think that the adjacency matrix of its line graph has -2 as an eigenvalue, but I don't know this can be helpful or not. 
furthermore, the number of vertices of $G$ should be even and $|E(G)|=\frac{3|V(G)|}{2}$.

I will be so thankful for your helpful comments and answers.

Comment: What do you mean Eigenvalue? Are we supposed to build a matrix from the graph? Like the laplacian or something?

Comment: maybe this help to relate: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incidence_matrix

Comment: Given the reference to $-2$ as an eigenvalue of the line graph, the obvious interpretation is the adjacency matrix.

Comment: I mean the eigenvalue of adjacency matrix of $G$. I edited my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The edges of the Petersen graph can be partitioned into three copies of your given graph, but its eigenvalues are 3, 1, $-2$. So the claim is false.

What is true is that if there is a partition as described then $-2$ is an eigenvalue. This is because if you pass to the line graph, the vertices
that correspond to the central edges of your subgraphs form a perfect 1-code
and if a regular graph has a perfect 1-code, it has $-1$ as an eigenvalue.
This gives an eigenvalue of $-2$ in the original graph.

Comment: Nice counter example dear Godsil!! Thank you very much. Your answer is very helpful for me.

Answer (score 1):

for the adjacency matrix of $G$ we can build an eigenvector $X$ where $AX=0$,for any vertex of degree 3,I mean similar to 1 and 2 put 2 and for others put -1,this vector will be the eigenvector of $\lambda=0$.

Comment: I cannot see how the vector you mentioned can be considered as an eigenvector of $G$ in general.

Comment: If we label each vertex of graph with its corresponding value of the eigenvector, for each vertex, in this case, the summation of labels of all neighbors must be zero. So your vector can not work.

Comment: but once I have checked it!by the way I tried to give an Idea!

Comment: Thanks alot. I understand.